# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: sql-server

I have been using a local database on my laptop for the last view weeks. But today I cannot access it. I get the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The system cannot find the file specified"

The database connection is: my-pc.C:\DB\DBV8.1.1.MDF.dbo

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987709/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-instance-remotely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under configuration manager I set the server browser to start (right click and start).

The following page/Answer gives more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987709/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-instance-remotely